# Using variables created in __init__ in other class

Tags: python-3.x

I use `self.marka` and `self.model` in `def opisz(self)`. These variables are created in `class Telefon` and I put them to print in other inherited `class Parametry`.

```
class Telefon(object):
    def co(self):
    print('To jest',self.marka,self.model,'. Kosztuje',self.cena,'zł.')

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.marka = input('Podaj marke telefonu')
        self.model = input('Podaj model telefonu')
        self.cena = input('Podaj cenę telefonu')

class Parametry(Telefon):
    def __init__(self, Telefon):
        self.marka = Telefon.marka
        self.model = Telefon.model
        self.system = input('Podaj system')
    def opisz(self):
        print(self.marka, self.model, 'posiada system', self.system)
tel = Telefon()
tel.co()
tel=Parametry()
tel.opisz()
```

My code gives me output like:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Telefon'

Comment: You have a typo: this line `print('To jest',self.marka,self.model,'. Kosztuje',self.cena,'zł.')` is not indented correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using correctly the call to the parent class constructor.

The following should work in Python3:

```py
class Telefon:
    def co(self):
        print('To jest',self.marka, self.model,'. Kosztuje',self.cena,'zł.')

    def __init__(self, marka, model, cena):
        self.marka = marka
        self.model = model
        self.cena = cena


class Parametry(Telefon):
    def __init__(self, system, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.system = system

    def opisz(self):
        print(self.marka, self.model, 'posiada system', self.system)

marka = input('Podaj marke telefonu')
model = input('Podaj model telefonu')
cena = input('Podaj cenę telefonu')
system = input('Podaj system')

tel = Parametry(system, marka=marka, model=model, cena=cena)
```

Comment: What do these lines do? Could you explain? 
def __init__(self, system, *args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)